# Problem requesting Bearer Token with Java HTTPRequest

Tags: java, https, oauth-2.0

I try to receive a bearer token from salesforce to access the API but I got stucked.

My Request looks like

```
    HttpURLConnection con;
    con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    if (con instanceof HttpsURLConnection)
    {
        Logger.log("HTTPS Post Request: " + authURL);
        ((HttpsURLConnection) con)
                .setHostnameVerifier(new MyHostNameVerifier());
    }

    String body = "grant_type=password" +
            "&username=" + user +
            "&password=" + password +
            "&client_id=" + client +
            "&client_secret=" + secret;

    // add request header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    con.setRequestProperty("user-Agent", "PostmanRuntime/7.3.0");
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    con.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    con.setRequestProperty("Host", apiHost);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + body.length());

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    wr.writeBytes(body);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

getting the response:

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        response.append(inputLine);


    return response.toString();
```

If I use this code with another API (not salesforce) it works absolutely perfect but on salesforce I got some strange binary response looking like

```
1FEFBFBD 08000000 00000000 5DEFBFBD 4F73EFBF BD3010EF BFBD3F4B EFBFBDEF BFBD4240 05EFBFBD 4C0F2842 EFBFBD1F EFBFBD2A 457AEFBF BD6442EF BFBD016C 1210EFBF BDEFBFBD 776FEFBF BDEFBFBD 71EFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBDEFBF BDEFBFBD EFBFBD5E 34EFBFBD 311102EF BFBDEFBF BD484A6D EFBFBD01 EFBFBDEF BFBD7D70 2B7F576F 1FEFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBDEFBF BD2E184C EFBFBDEF BFBD2C0E EFBFBDEF BFBD6076 EFBFBD7C 1AEFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBDEFBF BD24EFBF BD606756 EFBFBD64 73EFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBDEFBF BD45421C EFBFBDEF BFBDEFBF BD761570 23EFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBDEFBF BD0E6EEF BFBDEFBF BDEFBFBD 2CEFBFBD 650037EF BFBD42CA B65A3665 0032EFBF BDEFBFBD 5CEFBFBD EFBFBD27 EFBFBDEF BFBD42EF BFBD1213 5873EFBF BD36C8A5 3CEFBFBD EFBFBD61 642427EF BFBDEFBF BD1C234E 7AEFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBDEFBF BD0F32EF BFBDEFBF BDEFBFBD 0562447C 551C131D 57EFBFBD EFBFBD20 EFBFBD27 EFBFBD44 C8BB11EF BFBDEFBF BDEFBFBD EFBFBD5D EFBFBD1B 2B3404DD 8DEFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBD2E73 EFBFBD50 79EFBFBD EFBFBD00 657722EF BFBD7342 5436EFBF BD260851 EFBFBD14 22EFBFBD EFBFBD69 EFBFBDEF BFBD65EF BFBDEFBF BDEFBFBD EFBFBDEF BFBD3BEF BFBD2768 562259EF BFBD383E EFBFBD2C 61E8A388 57EFBFBD 0760EFBF BD7B5F46 EFBFBDEF BFBD3DEF BFBD4C0B 4C47357B EFBFBD06 EFBFBD3E EFBFBD5E EFBFBDEF BFBD3F03 2B50007D 010000
```

So I also fetch the response header and all looks good for me

```
20201021 08:05:04 Request SM Token
20201021 08:05:04 Get token
20201021 08:05:04 HTTPS Post Request: https://xxxxx/oauth2/token
20201021 08:05:05 Message: OK
20201021 08:05:05 Transfer-Encoding
20201021 08:05:05 chunked
20201021 08:05:05 X-ReadOnlyMode
20201021 08:05:05 false
20201021 08:05:05 Public-Key-Pins-Report-Only
20201021 08:05:05 pin-sha256="9n0izTnSRF+W4W4JTq51avSXkWhQB8duS2bxVLfzXsY="; pin-sha256="5kJvNEMw0KjrCAu7eXY5HZdvyCS13BbA0VJG1RSP91w="; pin-sha256="njN4rRG+22dNXAi+yb8e3UMypgzPUPHlv4+foULwl1g="; max-age=86400; includeSubDomains; report-uri="https://xxxx/hpkp-report/00D4F00000018vXm";
20201021 08:05:05 Date
20201021 08:05:05 Wed, 21 Oct 2020 08:05:05 GMT
20201021 08:05:05 X-Robots-Tag
20201021 08:05:05 none
20201021 08:05:05 Strict-Transport-Security 
20201021 08:05:05 max-age=31536002; includeSubDomains
20201021 08:05:05 Cache-Control
20201021 08:05:05 no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
20201021 08:05:05 X-B3-SpanId
20201021 08:05:05 c337af7bac4552ae
20201021 08:05:05 Content-Encoding
20201021 08:05:05 gzip
20201021 08:05:05 X-B3-Sampled 
20201021 08:05:05 0
20201021 08:05:05 Vary
20201021 08:05:05 Accept-Encoding
20201021 08:05:05 Set-Cookie
20201021 08:05:05 BrowserId=IQs6KxN0EeuvcP-sSWqJZQ; domain=.xxx.com; path=/; expires=Thu,21-Oct-2021 08:05:05 GMT; Max-Age=31536000
20201021 08:05:05 X-B3-TraceId
20201021 08:05:05 c337af7bac4552ae
20201021 08:05:05 Expires
20201021 08:05:05 Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
20201021 08:05:05 Content-Type
20201021 08:05:05 application/json;charset=UTF-8
20201021 08:05:05 Expect-CT
20201021 08:05:05 max-age=86400, report-uri="https://a.forcesslreports.com/Expect-CT-report/00D4F00000018vXm"
```

Doing the same request with Postman or CURL is working fine.

Anyone has an idea how I can go further here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I could find out, that the response body is zipped (Which is shown in the Headers at all. So my fault I didn't see that). When I unzip the response body everything works fine.
Nevertheless I wonder if a tool like Postman or curl is autodetecting that and unzipping the body before showing it to the user?
Or is there any "flag" I can set to force the auth server not to zip the response body?

Answer (score 0):

Check the Postman headers and compare them to the Request properties in your code. The problem might be this line:

```
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

try this instead:

```
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

Comment: When I set the Content-Type to JSON, I. cannot send a text body but must use a form data body which makes it much more complicated.

Comment: How does Postman send the request? (what are the headers)